# Error by creating my own scorer with make_scorer in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The `make_scorer` method of sklearn seems so simple in all the examples I see, but when I try to use it on my cross-validation, it gives me all NaN. Then I realize that something in `make_scorer` is not working but I cannot figure out what. I'll show you a small example:

```
a1 = np.array([0, 9, 0])
b1 = np.array([0, 8, 0])

def my_func(y_true, y_pred):
    output = y_true[1]-y_pred[1]
    return output

my_fake_scorer = make_scorer(my_func)
my_fake_scorer(y_pred=b1, y_true=a1)
```

If I run:

```
my_func(y_pred=b1, y_true=a1) --> 1 (ok!)
```

If I run:

```
my_fake_scorer(y_pred=b1, y_true=a1) -->

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17304/3405218040.py in <module>
     10 
     11 my_fake_scorer = make_scorer(my_func)
---> 12 my_fake_scorer(y_pred=b1, y_true=a1)

TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y_pred'
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) the `score_func` (in your case `my_func`) takes as input `y` and `y_pred`, while the scorer constructed with `make_scorer` (in your case `my_fake_scorer`) takes as input a (fitted) `estimator`, `X` and `y`.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

def score_func(y, y_pred):
    return y[1] - y_pred[1]

scorer = make_scorer(score_func=score_func)

X, y = make_regression(random_state=42)

estimator = LinearRegression()
estimator.fit(X, y)
scorer(estimator, X, y)
# 3.979039320256561e-13

cross_val_score(
    estimator=LinearRegression(),
    scoring=scorer,
    X=X,
    y=y,
    cv=3
)
# array([137.27979897,   5.44388795, -32.34674175])
```